# How to convert an xsl value to string?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I want to redirect the webpage to a value that is held in the xyz attribute.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=<xsl:value-of select="xyz"/>"></meta>
```

The above does not work. I tried a few other permutations and they dont work too.

What should I be looking for here? Some conversion operator to convert the value to a string so that I can redirect to it?

Comment: How does your xml looks ?

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way is to use `xsl:attribute`.
Then you should have something like this.

**XML**

```
<root>
  <redirects>
    <xyz url="http://www.example.com" />
  </redirects>
</root>
```

**HTML**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="root/redirects/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <meta>
          <xsl:attribute name="http-equiv">refresh</xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="content">0</xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="url"><xsl:value-of select="xyz"/></xsl:attribute>
        </meta>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I get an error saying `javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Syntax error in 'root/redirects/'.`. Is template matching needed?

Comment: If you leave it you should use `<xsl:value-of select="root/redirects/xyz"/>`.

Answer (score 1):

In literal result elements, attribute values are specified with attribute-value templates.  In an attribute-value template, portions of the value enclosed in braces are evaluated as XPath expressions.  So the effect you want can be achieved thus:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" 
      content="0; url={$xyz}" ></meta>
```

The use of explicit attribute constructors, as recommended by S. Visser, is also a perfectly good way to solve your problem.